# String Parsing - Recursively

Tags: recursion, expression

I have an string/expression like this:

```
(((p1 == 1) && (p2 != 2)) || p3 > 3) || (p4 < 5)
```

I want to parse this expression recursively in order to build a binary expression tree.

So, for this expression, the root would be || operator.

How can I build that algorithm?
Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the [Shunting-Yard Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm).

> In computer science, the **shunting-yard algorithm** is a method for
>   parsing mathematical expressions specified in infix notation. It can
>   be used to produce output in Reverse Polish notation (RPN) or as an
>   abstract syntax tree (AST). The algorithm was invented by Edsger
>   Dijkstra and named the "shunting yard" algorithm because its operation
>   resembles that of a railroad shunting yard.